# If-Then-Else clause in TIkZ Latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm continuing my work on the "changeable" graphics. I have an array of values, and I have already succeeded in making variables from it. The next step is that I want to ignore the zero values. Here it is, what I have a problem with:

```
\pgfmathifthenelse{\myq==0}{}{\fill (B) circle (4pt)};
```

I thought this code should draw a circle in the node `B` in case the variable `\myq` has non-zero value. But I cannot even compile the code, compilation freezes. Can you figure out the possible problem or give an advice?

The whole code is:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\zamkl{{3,4,4.5,5}}
\def\zamkh{{4,3.5,5,4.5}}
\def\zamkq{{20,0,30,0}}

\pgfmathparse{\zamkl[0]}
\edef\myl{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{\zamkh[0]}
\edef\myh{\pgfmathresult}

\pgfmathparse{\zamkq[0]}
\edef\myq{\pgfmathresult}

\draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (2*\myl,2*\myh);

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (\myl,0); \node at (B) [below] {$T$};
\coordinate (C) at (2*\myl,0);
\coordinate (D) at (2*\myl,\myh); \node at (D) [left] {$S$};
\coordinate (E) at (2*\myl,2*\myh);
\coordinate (F) at (\myl,2*\myh); \node at (F) [below] {$R$};
\coordinate (G) at (0,2*\myh);
\coordinate (H) at (0,\myh); \node at (H) [right] {$W$};

\draw [very thick] (A) -- (C) -- (E) --(G) -- (A);

\pgfmathifthenelse{\myq==0}{}{\fill (B) circle (4pt)};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `\ifnum\myq=0
 \relax
\else
 \fill (B) circle (4pt);
\fi`

Comment: Or `\ifthenelse{\myq=0}{}{\fill (B) circle (4pt)};`

Comment: Or `\pgfmathifthenelse{\myq==0}{}{"\noexpand\fill (B) circle (4pt);"}\pgfmathresult`

Comment: @esdd: your solution is the most correct according to OP's intentions; why don't you add an answer with all methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With pgfmath the correct syntax is

```
\pgfmathifthenelse{\myq==0}{}{"\noexpand\fill (B) circle (4pt);"}\pgfmathresult
```

or

```
\pgfmathparse{\myq==0?:"\noexpand\fill (B) circle (4pt);"}\pgfmathresult
```

Every expression is expanded with `\edef` before it is parsed. Using `\noexpand` protects `\fill` from this expansion. And as always `\pgfmathifthenelse` returns the result in the macro `\pgfmathresult`.